# Can Intel Identity Protection Technology be used to track browsing activity?

Tags: browser, privacy

So today I learned about [Intel Identity Protection Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/identity-protection/identity-protection-technology-general.html), and discovered it is installed as an add-on in my web browser (Firefox).

As someone who is concerned about privacy, I'm wondering if this technology could be used by advertisers or others to track my browsing activity online?  From their marketing materials (emphasis added):

> When a user visits a website that uses Intel® IPT from an Intel® IPT-enabled device, **after user opt-in**, the website can provision the embedded OTP token and bind it to that user’s account. The OTP token **generates a single-use password** that expires after just 30 seconds. Web properties of enterprises can use this OTP token in conjunction with a username and password to get strong two-factor authentication.

This makes it sound like it wouldn't be possible, but I think it still would be if the opt-in is "enforced" by the website (scout's honor), and if the mechanics of the OTP token allowed for the token to be tracked.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Who are you worried will be tracking your browsing activity?  Your ISP already knows every website you vist.

Comment: Personally concerned about advertising networks, I guess others might worry about government tracking.  ISP tracking can be avoided through VPN / proxy service, IPT might be a way for non-privacy-respecting websites to get around that.

Comment: advertising networks have more effective ways to track you then to use something that cannot be used to to track you.  Intel IPT is something the user has to interact with to setup, so its effective to use to authenticate yourself, but not really to track you.  The entire point of a OTP, is that it literally cannot be used more then once, by design.

Comment: If you can expand on that comment and make it an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: I wonder how this extension is actually useful in practice. Which websites use it? Adding any extension makes the browser potentially less stable and more vulnerable, so I'd rather not have a useless extension even if it looks harmless. And yes, I also do have it and I don't remember being asked if I wanted it.